Prevent ESLint removing distinction between String and string
I have the following function in TypeScript:
export function normalizeUrl(url: string | String | URL) {

When running ESLint (with eslint.configs.recommended and tseslint.configs.recommended rulesets only) this statement gets changed to:
export function normalizeUrl(url: string | string | URL) {

How do I prevent String being converted to string?
I've tried disabling no-new-wrappers globally but it has no effect. I can't find any other options that look relevant.
Note: This is for a package I maintain and users have requested in the past that I support passing in String objects, so I don't have the option of only accepting string primitives.

no-new-wrappers is an core ESLint (i.e. type-unaware) rule - have you looked at what's applied from TypeScript ESLint? There's only a few in the config you're using, finding https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-wrapper-object-types/ is pretty straightforward.

Thanks - I didn't spot that rule as I was looking for rules to do with String
